# disable add to cart for product with price 0

Tags: cart, addtocart

I was able to print a div when the price is 0 in this way

```
<?php if ($this->getProduct()->getFinalPrice()==0) : ?>
```

CALL NOW 123336541

```
<?php return; ?>
```

how do I disable add to cart when the price is 0?

Answer (score 1):

please try

`<?php if($_product->getPrice() != '0.00') {?>
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->quoteEscape($this->__('Add to Cart')) ?>"
                                        class="button btn-cart"
                                        onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')">
                                    <span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
<?php
}
?>`

Comment: in what file include this code?

Comment: to disable from **list page** you need to make change at app\design\frontend\{package_name}\{theme_name}\template\catalog\product\list.phtml

Comment: and to remove from product details page you need to make changes at app\design\frontend\{package_name}\{theme_name}\template\catalog\product\view\addtocart.phtml  **near line no 38-40**  and in list.phtml near line no  **90 and 153**

Answer (score 0):

have done so

on list.phtml

```
<?php if(!$_product->canConfigure() && $_product->isSaleable() && $_product->getPrice() != '0.00'): ?>
```

on addtocart.phml

```
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && ($_product->getPrice() != '0.00')):  ?>
```

add x to the end of the if conditions `($_product->getPrice() != '0.00')`